# Possible to do this without a loop?

Tags: c#, function, loops

I'm having trouble thinking of a solution to this problem that doesn't involve a loop. Basically, if something is greater than some arbitrary number, it loops around. Let's say 64 is the number.

```
0 => 0
32 => 32
64 => 64
96 => 32
128 => 64
160 => 32
192 => 64
```

Et cetera.

The way I'm currently doing it involves a while loop that checks to see if the value is over 64 and if it is, subtract 64 from it. Is there another way to do it that doesn't involve loops?

I'm using C# WinForms.

Comment: A recursive approach might prove to be more useful, if you can find the right cases.  Did you consider recursion?

Comment: I understand lines 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6. However according to your description, 196 should yield 196 -64 - 64 - 64 = 4. What am I missing in your question?

Comment: Woops typo. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: What should this operation return for numbers like 16?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static int filterNumber(int x, int arbitraryNumber) {
  if (x < arbitraryNumber) {
    return x;
  }

  int result = x % arbitraryNumber;
  if (result == 0) {
    return arbitraryNumber;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Mod the value by 64, it's an O(1) operation. Like this:

```
int number;
// number is initialized
number %= 64;
```

Comment: Doh. I was just using the modulus operator for something else too. I think I need some sleep.. heh. Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is O(1). The complexity classes (Big-O notation) are defined using Turing machines and you have to do O(n) operations on a turing machine. Just try to write a method for the operation without using integral division.

Comment: Also, with the modulus operator 64 % 64 is 0 and not 64. Same with 128 % 64. Is there yet another elegant solution around this?

Comment: @Gabriel I would agree that this is a O(1) operation. The overheard of executing modulo can be considered a constant (1 + C) which is reduced  to O(1) anyways.

Comment: @Oli as I said: C = O(n), you should try to write it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Modulo alone won't help in the case of equally divisible by 64.

```
if (number == 0)
    return 0;
var mod = number % 64;
return (mod == 0) ? 64 : mod;
```

Comment: This doesn't address the case where X % 64 yields a modulo of 0 (look at 128 returning 64)

Comment: If you want to name a variable, choose a good name - mod(ulus) is the name of the operation, its result is called rem(ainder). If you use ternary operator, why not to use it on first if? You just mix multiple concepts to make it harder to read.

Answer (score -1):

```
return n      == 0 ?  0 :
       n % 64 == 0 ? 64 :
       n % 32 == 0 ? 32 :
                     -1; // you have not specified this case in your examples!
```

Comment: Yes but as I mentioned on @Dinah's answer, mod alone doesn't cover the answer for multiples of 64 (which yield 0 and not 64 like the example shows)

Comment: @Gabriel: if x == 0, yours will not yield 0;

Comment: Agreed with Dinah... and I wasn't striving for the smallest and most obfuscated code possible. Tiny code doesn't mean elegant. Don't forget code is read way more than written, so don't shy away from descriptive var names etc.

Comment: @Oli: ok, hope this is understandable and I think it is also easier to understand, you can quickly check what it does. And it is even safer, because it shows unspecified case.

Comment: @Dinah: I just realized it before reading your comment, hope now it is ok.